# Ruby-rails-gems configuration mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I have weird problem with my machine.

There is a code(ruby on rails) which runs successfully on other machines but is not working on my machine.

It is like this: 
I am trying to submit a form with "post" method to my controller. But "routes.rb" can not mapped proper routs and I got exception "`ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to ContollerName.` )

Configuration on my machine:

```
manan@manan-shah:~$ ib.catman.manan $ gem --version
1.5.3
manan@manan-shah:~$ ib.catman.manan $ rails -v
Rails 2.3.8
manan@manan-shah:~$ ib.catman.manan $ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02

manan@manan-shah:~$ ib.catman.manan $ gem list 

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

aaronh-chronic (0.3.9)
access_control (0.0.1)
actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
acts_as_tree (0.1.1)
addressable (2.2.6)
authlogic (2.1.6)
backup (3.0.25)
barby (0.4.2)
builder (3.2.0)
bundler (1.6.0)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
cancan (1.5.1)
capistrano (2.14.2)
carmen (0.2.13)
chunky_png (1.2.6)
coderay (1.1.0)
compass (0.12.2)
crack (0.1.8)
css_parser (1.2.5)
daemons (1.0.10)
delayed-job-ajaycb (2.0.10)
easy-prof (1.0.0)
excon (0.14.3)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
fastercsv (1.5.4)
fastimage (1.2.8)
fog (1.4.0)
formatador (0.2.4)
formtastic (1.2.4)
fssm (0.2.9)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
grouped_validations (0.2.2)
haml (3.1.2)
highline (1.6.16)
hirb (0.7.1)
htmlentities (4.3.1)
httparty (0.8.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
jammit (0.6.5)
json (1.5.1)
less (1.2.21)
macaddr (1.6.1)
mail (2.4.0)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (1.21)
money (3.1.5)
multi_json (1.7.1)
multi_xml (0.5.1)
mutter (0.5.3)
mysql (2.8.1)
neography (0.0.25)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.6.3)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
open4 (1.3.0)
os (0.9.6)
paper_trail (1.6.5)
paperclip (2.3.11)
parallel (0.5.18)
Platform (0.4.0)
png (1.2.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
pony (1.2)
POpen4 (0.1.4)
premailer (1.7.3)
pry (0.9.12.4)
rack (1.1.6)
rails (2.3.8)
rake (10.2.2, 0.8.7)
rsolr (0.12.1)
rsolr-ext (0.12.1)
ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
ruby_parser (3.2.2)
rubygems-update (1.5.3)
RubyInline (3.9.0)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
rufus-decision (1.3.2)
rufus-dollar (1.0.4)
rufus-treechecker (1.0.8)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sass (3.2.0.alpha.278)
searchlogic (2.4.28)
sexp_processor (4.4.1)
slop (3.4.7)
ssl_requirement (0.1.0)
state_machine (0.9.4)
systemu (2.5.2)
thor (0.15.4)
treetop (1.4.12)
uuid (2.3.1)
validates_email_format_of (1.5.3)
whenever (0.6.2)
will_paginate (2.3.15)
wirble (0.1.3)
yui-compressor (0.9.6)
ZenTest (4.3.0)
zurb-foundation (3.0.5)
```

My problem:

- Same code-data works on the other machine, but not on my
  machine.
- What should the problem with my machine? Any configuration problem? Any bug of rails-ruby-gem?

Note:
 - I do not want any code modification because code is already on production (and it works well). I have just pulled my branch from the git there is no code change from my side.

Can anyone please help?

**-------------- EDIT -------------------**

```
rake routes
```

is not displaying that action with **POST** method.
**routes.rb** shows that action is configured with **GET** method.

is it possible to access some URL,  with some method(which is not listed in the output of "rake routes") ?

Comment: @WHO_HAS_DOWNVOTE_MY_QUESTION.... rather than, downvoting the question... can you please help me...? m newbie in this area...

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
rvm requirements
```

or

```
bundle install
```

and then try again

Comment: in other machine also i tried same... looks same in both machines

Comment: Can you post your routes.rb and your `rake routes` output please? (The significant parts) @MananShah

Comment: Also the path you are sending to in your form

Comment: Solved it.... :) format my pc and upgrading my ubuntu version from 12.04 to 14.04

Answer (score 1):

Please check your rails version same on both machine,if not try to install same rails version

```
rails -v
```

install specific version `gem install rails -v 3.0.1`.

Comment: same in both machine :(

Comment: have you compared all gem version? specially `formtastic`??

Comment: yes,we can use route which is not listed in the output of `rake routes`.But we have to define manually like ` match '/specific_url', :to => 'controller_name#action_name'`

Comment: i have already upvoted your answer... but not accept it yet... because my problem is still there.

Comment: Solved it.... :) format my pc and upgrading my ubuntu version from 12.04 to 14.04